# Read CSV files as a single string in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, read.csv

I have a couple of .csv files that contain strings of text. I need a way for RStudio to store the string of texts and their file names as a dataFrame.

`uniqueName_KIwwciwldv.csv` contains `Hello, I, contain, some numbers like, 12, 10.321`

What I want is that I should be able to create a single dataframe with column names like:

```r
head(df)

uniqueID                 text
uniqueName_KIwwciwldv    "Hello, I, contain, some numbers like, 12, 10.321"
```

I have tried to read csv but then it assigns individual values to columns (not something I want).

Comment: use `readLines`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some combination of `list.files` and `readLines`  could help

```
csv_files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")
Text <- purrr::map_chr(csv_files, readLines)

data.frame(UniqueID = gsub("\\.csv", "", csv_files), 
       text=Text)
                                         text
1         uniqueName_KIwwciwldv    Hello, I, contain, some numbers like, 12, 10.321
2 uniqueName_KIwwciwldv_letters    Hello, I, contain, some letters like, A, B, C
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. Can you please explain the map_chr function?

Comment: `map_chr` belongs to purrr package and it iterates over a list or a vector applying a function (`readLines`) and returning an object of class character. Read [`map_chr`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) for futher details.